# How do I start seeing an Event Log message that I chose to not see again?

Tags: intellij-idea

In my Event Log in Intellij IDEA 2016, I used to see this message:

> Unlinked Gradle project?
>   [Import Gradle project](http://example.com), this will also enable Gradle Tool Window.
>   Don't want to see the message for the project again: [press here](http://example.com).

At some point, I clicked on the "press here" link indicating that I don't want to see the message again. Since then, I have decided that I'd like to see it again.

How do I start seeing this Event Log message that I chose to not see again?

Answer (score 1):

You can re-enable notifications balloon popups and logs from the (obviously) `Notifications` settings window, which you can open in (at least) 2 ways:

1) From the `Event log` window click on the settings button

[image: event log]

2) `File` -> `Settings` -> `Appearance & behaviour` -> `Notifications`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the specific notification that has been asked about (`Unlinked Gradle Project?`). **The only way that I found to re-enable the notification was to delete the `.idea` folder inside the project and re-open the project in Intellij**.

Other notifications, such as `Maven: non-managed pom.xml` work as expected so this bug is specific to the `Unlinked Gradle Project?` notification.

This appears to be a bug in Intellij Idea as of this build:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5
Build #IU-162.2228.15, built on October 14, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-287-b2 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

I have raised an issue for this : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162936

Also, I found that these notification settings are not stored in a project specific file. This file, on OSX, is `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2016.2/options/notifications.xml`, on Windows it would reside in a folder according to [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs).

These were the contents of the file for me, when I was testing this notification:

```
<application>
  <component name="NotificationConfiguration">
    <notification groupId="Gradle Notification Group" shouldReadAloud="true" />
    <notification groupId="Maven: non-managed pom.xml" displayType="STICKY_BALLOON" shouldLog="false" />
    <notification groupId="Project Startup Tasks Messages" displayType="STICKY_BALLOON" />
  </component>
</application>
```

I noticed that changing the Popup Type for 'Gradle Notification Group' correctly updates `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2016.2/options/notifications.xml`, however even when the Popup type is 'BALLOON' or 'STICKY_BALLOON', it does not result in Intellij re-notifying the user about the `Unlinked gradle project`.